# If for the first $\|n\|$ primes $p_i, \left(\frac{p_i}n\right)=+1$, then $n$ is a square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, riemann-hypothesis

Can we prove or disprove (perhaps under some standard hypothesis):
$$\text{If for the first }\|n\|\text{ primes }p_i, \left(\dfrac{p_i} n\right)=+1,\text{ then }n\text{ is a square.}$$

where $\|n\|$ is the number of bits in $n$, $\left(\dfrac p n\right)$ is the [Kronecker symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_symbol), and $p_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ prime, starting with $p_1=2$. By contraposition, the proposition can also be stated as:
$$\text{If }n\in\mathbb N\text{ is not a square, then }\exists\,i\in\mathbb N^*\text{ with }2^{i-1}\le n\text{ and }\left(\dfrac{p_i}n\right)\ne+1$$

I don't know a counterexample for the stronger proposition with $2^i\le n$.

The proposition holds

- For $n=0$, $n=1$, and more generally any $n$ that is a square.
- For even $n>0$, since for these $\left(\frac 2 n\right)=0\ne+1$. Thus we can restrict to odd $n$ and use the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) rather than the Kronecker symbol.
- If $n\bmod8\in\{3,5\}$, since for these $\left(\frac 2 n\right)=-1\ne+1$.

We can thus focus on $n\equiv\pm1\pmod8$, and turn to use of the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol):

- for $n\equiv+1\pmod8$ and odd $p_i$, we can change $\left(\dfrac{p_i} n\right)=+1$ to $\left(\dfrac n{p_i}\right)=+1$
- for $n\equiv-1\pmod8$ and odd $p_i$, we can change $\left(\dfrac{p_i} n\right)=+1$ to $\left(\dfrac {-n}{p_i}\right)=+1$.

A closely related problem is studied by Richard F. Lukes, C. D. Patterson and Hugh C. Williams, [*Some results on pseudosquares*](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00678-3/S0025-5718-96-00678-3.pdf#page=9), [Math. Comp. 65 (1996)](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-96-00678-3), 361-372. The smallest $n$ for a given $i$ are the *positive pseudosquares* for $n\equiv+1\pmod8$, *negative pseudosquares* for $n\equiv-1\pmod8$. See [A002189](https://oeis.org/A002189) and [A045535](https://oeis.org/A045535).

Initial motivation: In some primality test algorithms we need the smallest $p_i$ with $\left(\dfrac{p_i}n\right)\ne+1$. The proposition tells that when finding none for $i\in\left[1,\|n\|\,\right]$, we can stop and declare there's no such $p_i$ since $n$ must be a square. If it was true, the proposition would avoid making an explicit square test.

Remark (not quite an argument): for a fixed small prime $p$ and a large random $n$, there is  probability $\dfrac{p+1}{2p}>\dfrac 1 2$ that $\left(\dfrac p n\right)\ne+1$. The probabilities for small $p_i$ are only vanishingly correlated.

---

If we look at how many such tests we need, here are
◦ smallest non-square odd $n$ record-holders for high $\pi(p)$
◦ the smallest $p$ with $\left(\frac p n\right)\ne+1$
◦ the number $\|n\|$ of bits of $n$
◦ the index $\pi(p)$ per the prime counting function
◦ the margin $\Delta=\|n\|-\pi(p)$ there is for the proposition
◦ the kind of pseudosquare $n$: $-$ for $n\equiv-1\pmod8$, $+$ for $n\equiv+1\pmod8$
◦ the factorization of $n$ when composite

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|c|c|l|}
\hline
n&p&\!\|n\|\!&\pi(p)\!&\Delta&\text{kind}&\text{factors of }n\\
\hline
2&2&2&1&1&&\text{Prime}\\
7&3&3&2&1&-&\text{Prime}\\
23&5&5&3&2&-&\text{Prime}\\
71&7&7&4&3&-&\text{Prime}\\
311&11&9&5&4&-&\text{Prime}\\
479&13&9&6&3&-&\text{Prime}\\
1559&17&11&7&4&-&\text{Prime}\\
5711&19&13&8&5&-&\text{Prime}\\
10559&23&14&9&5&-&\text{Prime}\\
18191&29&15&10&5&-&\text{Prime}\\
31391&31&15&11&4&-&\text{Prime}\\
118271&37&17&12&5&-&101\cdot1171\\
366791&43&19&14&5&-&\text{Prime}\\
2155919&59&22&17&5&-&59\cdot36541\\
6077111&67&23&19&4&-&1039\cdot5849\\
98538359&71&27&20&7&-&79\cdot1247321\\
120293879&73&27&21&6&-&\text{Prime}\\
131486759&83&27&23&4&-&\text{Prime}\\
508095719&89&29&24&5&-&367\cdot547\cdot2531\\
2570169839&113&32&30&2&-&439\cdot5854601\\
196265095009&131&38&32&6&+&\text{Prime}\\
513928659191&137&39&33&6&-&\text{Prime}\\
844276851239&139&40&34&6&-&794239\cdot1063001\\
1043702750999&149&40&35&5&-&389\cdot5689\cdot471619\\
4306732833311&151&42&36&6&-&\text{Prime}\\
8402847753431&157&43&37&6&-&\text{Prime}\\
47375970146951&163&46&38&8&-&151717\cdot312265403\\
52717232543951&167&46&39&7&-&223\cdot1747\cdot6863\cdot19717\\
100535431791791&173&47&40&7&-&9873817\cdot10182023\\
178936222537081&181&48&42&6&+&\text{Prime}\\
493092541684679&193&49&44&5&-&4723\cdot104402401373\\
1088144332169831&223&50&48&2&-&293\cdot464941\cdot7987687\\
11641399247947921&227&54&49&5&+&\text{Prime}\\
88163809868323439&229&57&50&7&-&96757\cdot911187923027\\
196640248121928601&233&58&51&7&+&\text{Prime}\\
423414931359807911&239&59&52&7&-&241\cdot1756908428878871\\
695681268077667119&241&60&53&7&-&3413\cdot203832777051763\\
1116971853972029831&257&60&55&5&-&1721\cdot869521\cdot746416591\\
3546374752298322551&271&62&58&4&-&\text{Prime}\\
10198100582046287689&277&64&59&5&+&277\cdot1091\cdot1151\cdot29318344777\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Values are extracted from Richard F. Lukes, [*A Very Fast Electronic Number Sieve*](https://mspace.lib.umanitoba.ca/bitstream/handle/1993/12210/Lukes_A_very.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y#page=159), thesis presented to the University of Manitoba (1995), tables 6.22 (negative pseudosquares [A045535](https://oeis.org/A045535)) and 6.24 (positive pseudosquares [A002189](https://oeis.org/A002189)), and in the process of being independently verified.
The terms to $\pi(p)=50$ also are in Nathan D. Bronson and Duncan A. Buell, *Congruential Sieves on FPGA Computers*, in [Proceedings of Symposia in Applied Mathematics, Volume 48, 1994](https://doi.org/10.1090/psapm/048), 547-551.

Comment: Do you mean "If a $k$-bit integer $n$ is not a square"? And do you really need there to be exactly one prime $p$, or just at least one?

Comment: You have your $p$ and $||n||$ headings the wrong way round.

Comment: This kind of problem in ANT is very hard in general; as far as I know, if even a probabilistic heuristic does not give the answer, then nothing within known Analytic NT will.

Comment: Could you explain why you have the $p_i$'s in the top, and the $n$ in the bottom, of the quadratic symbol? The reason I ask is that having the $n$ in the top and the $p_i$'s in the bottom seems a more natural way to say "$n$ is a square modulo these primes"... Could you clarify, please? :)

Comment: @paul garrett: I now explain the original motivation in the question, and explain how to reduce the problem to the Legendre symbol $\left(\dfrac n{p_i}\right)$. That's an improvement, thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 10):

This is not known.

*However,* it may be provably false under the [Generalized Riemann Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis) (GRH), depending on a constant calculated in a paper of Montgomery.

#### Least Quadratic Non-Residue

You are looking at the first $\log_2 n$ primes, the largest of which has size $\sim \log_2(n)\cdot \log\log(n)$, and asking if $\left(\frac{p}{n}\right)$ is $1$ for all of these primes, must $n$ be a square?

> **Equivalent Statement of Question:** If $\left(\frac{p}{n}\right)=1$ for all primes $$p\leq (1+o_n(1)) \log_2 n \log\log n,$$ does it imply that $n$ is a square?

This problem is related to the *least quadratic non-residue* modulo $p$, which we denote by $n_p$.

If it is possible for the numbers $1,2,\dots,k$ to *all* be quadratic residues modulo $q$ for a sufficiently large $k>(1+\epsilon)\log_2(n)\cdot \log\log(n)$, this would disprove your proposition. This leads to the following claim:

---

#### Proposition:

For your proposition to be true, we must have $$n_q \leq \left(\frac{1}{\log 2}+o_q(1)\right)\log q \log \log q$$ for all primes $q$. If there exist $C>1$, and infinitely many primes such that $$n_q>\frac{C\log q \cdot \log \log q}{\log 2},$$ then your proposition is false.

---

#### Current Knowledge of $n_q$:

Under GRH, the following lower bound due to Montgomery 1971 $$ n_p = \Omega(\log p \log \log p)$$  and the following upper bound due to Ankeny 1952  $$n_p=O\left(\log p)^2\right).$$

If the constant in Montgomery's lower bound is large enough, it would disprove your conjecture under GRH. I am not particularly familiar with Montgomery's method, but based on [some results in this paper of Granville and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206031), I believe that it may be possible to show that the hypothesis of the claim above does hold for some $C>1$, and hence that your proposition is false under GRH.

Comment: May I ask how does your claim relate to OP's proposition?

Comment: @ShengtongZhang: I added some more details to the answer

Comment: The reference to Montgomery is: Hugh Lowell Montgomery, [_Topics in multiplicative number theory_](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0060851), Lecture Notes in Math. 227, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1971.

Comment: @fgrieu: That is correct, that is the lower bound result of Montgomery. I looked through it briefly, and I did not see any calculation of the constant.